# Characterizations of continuous, closed, and open maps

Tags: general-topology, continuity, open-map, closed-map

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a map of topological spaces. There are several characterizations for $f$ to be continuous, closed, or open, usually in terms of pre-images, closures, and interiors of sets. Here is what I think I know:

$f$ is continuous $\iff$ $\forall B \subseteq Y, \overline{f^{-1}(B)}\subseteq f^{-1}(\overline{B})$ $\iff$ $\forall A\subseteq X, f(\overline{A})\subseteq \overline{f(A)}$.

$f$ is closed $\iff$ $\forall A \subseteq X$, $\overline{f(A)} \subseteq f(\overline{A})$

$f$ is open $\iff$ $\forall A \subseteq X$, $f(A^\circ) \subseteq f(A)^\circ$ $\Rightarrow \forall B\subseteq Y, f^{-1}(\overline{B})\subseteq \overline{f^{-1}(B)}$. (I'm actually not sure if the reverse implication holds for this last statement).

Is there some "comprehensive" list of characterizations similar to these? Does the reverse implication hold for the last statement?

Comment: No, in this case, your last statement is incorrect, since it requires $f^{-1}$ to be continuous which is not in the assumption.

Comment: You might be interested in my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892976/operator-characterizations-of-continuity-and-co-continuity which is currently deleted simply because nobody was interested.

Comment: Some posts which seem related: [Characterizing continuous, open and closed maps via interior and closure operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4565434) and [Characterization of Continuous, Closed and Open maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4564006).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that $f$ continuous iff every inverse image of an open set is open is the default definition. All other statements equivalent to it are "characterisations" of continuity in terms of different notions.
They can serve as *definitions* in other contexts; e.g. when we define a closure space instead of a topology, we can use the characterisation using closures from topology as a motivation for a definition of "closure-continuity", as it were.

Ditto for $f$ open iff images of open sets are open, and closed 
maps too. The other equivalences I would not call definitions but characterisations of that notion. Similarly we could then define "closure-closed map" in a closure space, etc.

For continuity we can add

$$\forall B \subseteq Y: f^{-1}[B^\circ] \subseteq (f^{-1}[B])^\circ\tag{1}$$
$$\forall B \subseteq Y: \partial f^{-1}[B] \subseteq f^{-1}[\partial B]\tag{2}$$
to the list. The last one in terms of the boundary $\partial$ of sets (which is of rarer interest).

Characterisations of open and closed maps are rarer (in my books at least).

I believe the following reverse inclusions (i.e. reverse to the continuity case) do characterise openness of $f$:

$$\forall B \subseteq Y: f^{-1}[\partial B] \subseteq \partial f^{-1}[B]\tag{3}$$
$$\forall B \subseteq Y: f^{-1}[\overline{B}] \subseteq \overline{f^{-1}[B]}\tag{4}$$

(I have some proofs in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3353766/4280); see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1832039/4280) etc.)

I haven't seen another one in terms of interior, or a closed map characterisation in interior-terms. Maybe look for those yourself.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, "characterizations" is more appropriate (I have edited the question). A proof of the reverse implication I asked for can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393354/characterization-of-open-maps?rq=1